How are the device names of disks constructed in Windows?
Can I construct the device names manually instead of using some API? For example, I want to use the Physical Drive 2, but the following code fails(hDrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE):
        QString drivePath = QString("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2");
        HANDLE hDrive = CreateFileW((LPCWSTR)drivePath.utf16(), GENERIC_READ,
                                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                    0, NULL);

        if (hDrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to open drive 2";
        }

Is there any simple pattern for disk device names like \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive*, so I can replace * with a number and try until the CreateFileW function succeeds? In Linux, the disk device name is like /dev/sda, /dev/sdb,..., so I can always try till succeed.
In Qt, I can list device names using QStorageInfo but only limited to mounted devices. For unmounted devices, how can I get their device names?
